# How to check if a Viewpoint exist in a particular Geometry/Envelope in ArcGIS Runtime Mobile SDK

Tags: android, ios, geometry, arcgis-runtime, viewpoint

I have a ArcGIS runtime map setup in my mobile app for both android and ios. Now, I have some viewpoints listing which I want to check if exist on some particular map area i.e. some specific Map Extent/Envelope/Geometry.

Is there any way we can implement this functionality?

Please help me out!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AGSGeometryEngine's [geometry:intersectsGeometry:()](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_geometry_engine.html#a895f69a30cd7c2306919765ed7919538) function to check whether viewpoint's geometry intersects with the specific map extent/envelope/geometry or not.

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Nimesh

Comment: I would add that there are numerous geometry relationship functions on GeometryEngine which tell you how one geometry relates to another. There's some good conceptual doc on this here: http://esri.github.io/geometry-api-java/doc/RelationalOperators.html